# Add 2 UIImages into One UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image, sdk

I am adding 2 images to each other and wanted to know if this is a good way to do this? This code works and looked to be powerful.

So,  my question really is, It this good or is there a better way?

PS: Warning code written by a designer.

Call the function:

```
- (IBAction) {
    UIImage *MyFirstImage = UIImage imageNamed: @"Image.png"];
    UIImage *MyTopImage = UIImage imageNamed: @"Image2.png"];
    CGFloat yFloat = 50;
    CGFloat xFloat = 50;
    UIImage  *newImage =   [self placeImageOnImage:MyFirstImage imageOver:MyTopImage x:&xFloat y:&yFloat];
}
```

The Function:

```
- (UIImage*) placeImageOnImage:(UIImage *)image topImage:(UIImage *)topImage x:(CGFloat *)x y:(CGFloat *)y {    
    // if you want the image to be added next to the image make this CGSize bigger.  
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width,image.size.height); 

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
    [topImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(*x,*y,topImage.size.width,topImage.size.height)];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeDestinationOver alpha:1];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't really improve on that!

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK. Perhaps you don't really need the `CGFloat` pointers, but that's fine, too.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is correct. There is no better way to do what you want.

Minuses:
1) Consider `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` method. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` isn't good for retina. 
2) Don't pass floats as pointers. Use `x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y instead`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the begin context version, `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`, that allows you to specify options for scale (and pass 0 as the scale) do you don't lose any quality on retina displays.

Comment: I will look into UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and repost the  code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want one image drawn on top of another image, just draw the one in back, then the one in front, exactly as if you were using paint. There is no need to use blend modes.

```
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
[topImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(*x,*y,topImage.size.width,topImage.size.height)];
```